# Which partition is my OS installed on?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I want to know which partition OS installed on my server. 
Below is the `fdisk` and `df` command outputs from my server.

```
[root@ ~]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.3 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14        1058     8393962+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3            1059        7457    51399967+  83  Linux

[root@ ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3              48G   12G   34G  26% /
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

I noticed that `sda1` has an asterisk on the `Boot` field. Does it signify that the OS is installed in that partition?

[I also came upon this article](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/partitioning-your-hard-drive-during-a-linux-install/), but I just want to confirm if the OS is installed on `sda1`.

Is there any linux command to run or files to open to see which partition the OS is installed on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well technically speaking, in your case, it's installed on two partitions - sda1 and sda3. sda1 is mounted as /boot. This is where the kernel is held. sda3 is the root partition, where the rest of the OS is installed.

Comment: Thanks @EEAA. That is why I cannot unmount sda3. I was supposed to resize that partition. Anyways that would be for another question. Thanks.

Comment: If you consider swap space as part of the OS (I do) then technically it's on *three* partitions (the swap space is on `/dev/sda3`, and while you *can* run a Linux system without swap this one is probably configured to expect it and might do Bad Things if it were not present).  Your OS *files* though are on the partitions mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternate (lower level) way of looking at things from [EEAA's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/451126/32986), your OS is installed on `/dev/sda` -- all three partitions you've listed are required for proper functioning of your system.

- `/dev/sda3` is `/` - the root filesystem.
  All the stuff you deal with when using your system is located on this partition.
- `/dev/sda1` is `/boot` - as the name implies this is where Linux puts "bootup stuff"
  This includes GRUB configurations, kernel modules, etc.
- `/dev/sda2` is your `[SWAP]` partition.
  Linux uses this as a place to shove program data if you use up all your RAM.
  As your system is apparently configured to expect a swap partition you need this to boot, otherwise when Linux tries to activate swap it will throw an error and ask you to fix it on the console.

NOT SHOWN: The boot block (the really tiny bit of code that gets things going after BIOS is done with its power-on tasks).
The boot block get put in the first disk block of the boot drive (almost certainly `/dev/sda` in your case), and is really "outside" of the partition layout that you see with `df` or `fdisk`.

---

Regarding the link you posted, for more information on partitioning, see [this question and its related answers](https://serverfault.com/questions/449395/unix-server-partitioning-filesystem-layout), you may find it interesting.

Comment: Sorry for editing your answer, but you misplaced /dev/sda1 and /dev/sda3, and this in fact completely reversed your answer's meaning.

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand - 
Your OS is installed on /dev/sda3 as you can see it is mounted on /

The system will boot from sda1

Comment: The system will require the files in `/boot` (little things like the GRUB configuration and the kernel) in order to actually boot...