# Linux partitioning suggestion for failover setup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drbd

I've been using Ubuntu for a while but didn't really paid attention on partitioning and just accepted the defaults.

But on a new project we plan on setting up two old servers HP DL380 G3 both would have identical components with 2 x RAID 1 SCSI volumes at 72GB. This will be setup with DRBD for failover.

The server's main function will only serve as a firewall using IPTables no other apps will be installed except for some network monitoring tools, then 2 or 3 additional users maybe.

Due to the limited disk space I want to keep the partition simple.

```
/ (root) 
/var/log (mostly for firewall logs) 
(swap)
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to ask "How should I partition my server?" There's a lot of information on [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/449395/unix-server-partitioning-filesystem-layout) that would help you...

Comment: I'd like to suggest not setting up two G3 servers because... well, that's just silly.  You'd probably save enough on juice and cooling alone to justify a small plug server or something running a low power CPU, like an atom.

Comment: @voretaq7 - thanks for sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

Failover in this case isn't really going to have any impact on partitioning.  A standard partitioning scheme on both should work just fine.

I also agree with HopelessN00b's comment; you'll spend more in power in a year powering one G3 than the cost of a suitable new, enterprise grade desktop machine.

Comment: HopelessN00b : you are both right on the power consumption I just don't have any choice right now. So I was thinking maybe I'll remove the second RAID volume and take out hot spares to save a bit.

Comment: Honestly, I think it'll be the fat cpu, high speed fans, and other massive power consumption; your hard drives will be the least of your power consumption issues.  In fact, if *all* it is going to be is a firewall, you'd be fine with a diskless setup (i.e. boot from a custom configured DVD or USB.)

Answer (score 0):

As you won't need much space for the base system I would recommend to use as much space as possible for LVM. Maybe like 10 to 20 GB for /, a few GB for swap and /var (or /var/log) as a logical volume. This way you're very fexible, for example you can increase /var when needed or if you ever use it for another service you can create a new logical volume for that.

By the way, on a firewall DRBD doesn't make much sense IMHO, as most of your important data (iptable rules, configuration) is staic anyway. You could use for example [csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/) to keep configuration on both hosts in sync.